# Audio file in Python not playing

Tags: python, audio, wave

I tried to play an audio file in python, but after a few seconds, I got the following issue:

```
Expression 'ret' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1736
Expression 'AlsaOpen( &alsaApi->baseHostApiRep, params, streamDir, &self->pcm )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1904
Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_Initialize( &self->playback, alsaApi, outParams, StreamDirection_Out, NULL != callback )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2175
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Initialize( stream, alsaHostApi, inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, callback, streamFlags, userData )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2840
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/LUNA/Schlafzimmer/Audio.py", line 157, in putout
    frames_per_buffer=self.playback_audio_format['chunk'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9985] Device unavailable
```

I am using "import wave" for opening the audio-file.

Comment: "Device unavailable". Whatever device you're trying to use, it seems that's the wrong name or disabled by the RPi.

Comment: Or it might need elevated access.

Comment: Yes, so running as `sudo` might help

Comment: So the audio file is played for about 30 seconds and only then does the error come